# Check if an image exists in a web page

Tags: vbscript

I am automating a web application using VBScript. Now my problem is, if I click on any link or button in the web page, it's taking some time to load the web page, but the URL remains constant. So my script should wait until the loading is completed.

The following code is not helping me:

```
Do While objIE.Busy
  DoEvents
Loop
```

Actually, when the page is loading, an image (Loading-Indicator) is displayed on the web page. So I am trying to identify if the image and wait until the image exists on the page and then continue.

I want some thing like:

```
Do while Image (Loading-Indicator).exists
  DoEvents
Loop
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not possible. You can't access the content of a page unless it has reached [`READYSTATE_COMPLETE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), at which point the value of the `Busy` property becomes `False`.

Please explain why you can't use

```
Do While objIE.Busy
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

or

```
Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop
```

to wait for the page to finish loading.

---

**Edit:** To wait for the application to finish starting after the page is loaded you could do something like this:

```
'wait for page content to become accessible
Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

'wait for application to finish starting
Do Until IsNull(objIE.document.getElementById("loadind"))
  DoEvents
Loop
```

if an `<img>` element with the ID `loadind` is displayed as long as the application is starting.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance.. The problem with Do While objIE.Busy is Script will wait until Browser gets loaded but its not waiting while application is getting loaded.

Comment: @KamichettySiva Have you tried `Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4`?

Comment: Yes, I have used, But same thing is happening. Script is not waiting while application is getting loaded.

Comment: @KamichettySiva Updated my answer. Please see if that helps. If not, you need to provide more information about what is being displayed during application startup.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers, I Have tried in the way as u suggested. In this case the control is not coming out of the loop even the application is fully loaded.

Comment: @KamichettySiva That suggests that the image is not removed after the application finished loading. Could you invert the check and try to detect something that is only displayed after the application is fully loaded? For further help you'd need to provide more information about the page.

Comment: @ Ansgar Wiechers Thanks alot, I got the solution. I have found that some objects are displayed only after the application is fully loaded. I have tried it in the following way and its working.                              9: Set header = objIE.document.getElementById("btnFind")
If header Is Nothing Then GoTo 9                          header.click